# Dependence of pitch on airspeed in vessel istruments

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics

Why, unlike Helmotz resonance's model, does blowing more or less strongly vary the pitch of the note produced in a vessel instrument, like ocarina? Obviously the model is very simplified and approximate, but what are the non-linear effects involved? Is there an intuitive way to explain them?
Thanks in advance.